# How to switch between two Vim windows (two separate instances) on separate monitors

Tags: vim, text-editors, macvim, multiple-monitors

Whats the keyboard shortcut to switch between running instances of Vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Giving a second monitor to someone who doesn't know how to navigate between windows with the keyboard is **mean**.

[This list of keyboard shortcuts](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343) will probably help you. Try <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>, for example. That's a backtick, by the way.

I use Exposé for that kind of thing.

Comment: In my defense I can switch between applications on the different monitors, just not two instances of Vim. The keyboard shortcuts are good to know, but not solving my problem. Expose, which I think now is Mission Control, works okay but I'd rather just have a simple shortcut to get to the other monitor. Not sure why this is so difficult to pull off...

Comment: What is difficult? I gave you exactly what you asked: you hit Cmd+` in one MacVim window and the next one takes the focus. Easy. If you want a general shortcut to move your cursor to the second screen that's an entirely different question because, at a high level (the user level), Mac OS X doesn't really consider your second screen as another entity. It does, at lower level, though. I know for sure that you could reach your underlying goal with a bit of AppleScript.

Comment: Okay, I was being mildly retarded, not recognizing the character as 'backtick' but seeing it as an apostrophe. Which is my bad. That solution works. I'm going to remap it, though. For curiosity sake, if you use a multi-monitor set-up, do you use two Vim windows?

Comment: At work I am the very happy user of two perfectly calibrated 22" EIZO monitors but I rarely if ever have code on the two screens. Usually, I use Vim how it is supposed to be used, juggling with buffers and splits in a single (often maximised) GUI window, while the other monitor is dedicated to documentation and/or photoshop comps and/or a browser window.